# Most efficient way to retrieve data by timestamps

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.8.

I have table like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    foo_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    -- other columns, constraints
)
```

This table contains about 4.000.000 rows. One day data is about 50.000 rows.

My goal is to retrieve one day data as fast as possible.

I have created an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_foo_date_idx
ON foo
USING btree
      (date_trunc('day'::text, foo_date));
```

And now I'm selecting data like this (`now()` is just an example, i need data from ANY day):

```
select * 
from process 
where date_trunc('day'::text, now()) = date_trunc('day'::text, foo_date)
```

This query lasts about 20 s.

Is there any possiblity to obtain same data in shorter time?

Comment: Does your table has a primary key? Is `foo_date` part of it? (IMO foo_date should at least be part of one of foos candidate keys)

Comment: @joop foo contains primary keys - simple `bigint` id. `foo_date` is not a part of it

Comment: Are you retrieving this data and displaying it on your screen? Just to get 50,000 rows across a network connection is going to take time, as is the UI displaying those rows. It might not be an issue with the server retrieving those rows, but the bottleneck might be elsewhere. I don't know the PostgreSQL tools well enough to point you to where you can check this, but maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 1):

It takes time to retrieve 50,000 rows.  20 seconds seems like a long time, but if the rows are wide, then that might be an issue.

You can directly index `foo_date` and use inequalities.  So, you might try this version:

```
create index foo_foo_date_idx2 on foo(foo_date);

select p
from process p
where p.foo_date >= date_trunc('day', now()) and
      p.foo_date < date_trunc('day', now() + interval '1 day');
```